# Diff between Fortify on-demand and on-premise

Tags: jenkins, fortify

What is the difference between HPE Fortify on-Demand and on-premise?

I'm trying to setup fortify with jenkins which is running on amazon cloud. Need suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

My comments are my own, and do not necessarily reflect the view of my employer.

I've used both.  If you're sold on Fortify, then you should use the on premise version.  If you're open to using other tools, then you should ask if Fortify is right for you.

The short reason why is that Fortify on Demand often does not work for automation.  It has too many problems, and Fortify Support will spend a lot more effort trying to get you to do something manual rather than trying to fix the problems.

Now let's break it down on the pros and cons of each.

### **Fortify on Premise**

With substantial effort and/or cost, you can setup Fortify on Premise to efficiently work in a DevSecOps Environment.  In between the development environment and the Fortify SSC server, it is advisable to have an environment, such as a Jenkins server, than the Fortify scanning happens from.  This middle environment receives the code from the dev environment, scans it, and uploads the results to Fortify SSC (the on-premise server).  If there are problems, having this middle environment will be essential for efficiently debugging -- as the AppSec team will have complete control and visibility over it.  The AppSec team will have to maintain the middle environment, Fortify SSC, and provide a script to developers to upload their code to the middle environment.  Such a setup can be used to achieve security and raise the bar in secure coding practices in a corporate environment, but it takes time to set that up.

Pros:

- You are completely in control, and can efficiently debug problems, which is important because there will *always* be problems.
- It allows you to efficiently scale security
- Fortify scan engine is really powerful.

Cons:

- Substantial setup effort
- You must maintain the environments
- Fortify always has a lot of false positives
- Fortify scanning is slow
- Fortify requires being able to build (for most languages) to perform its best scanning, and this will bite you in a number of ways
- Fortify is not so developer friendly
- You often need to dig deep to figure out if a Fortify finding is on to something special, or if it is just "full of it."  It takes time to understand the beast.

### **Fortify on Demand**

The appeal for Fortify on Demand is that you should not need all that setup to efficiently scan your code bases.  In addition, they provide Jenkins and VSTS plugins to put in your developer build environment, they upload the code to the cloud server, the scan happens there, and you get the results.  It would seem that they made it easier for you to have build integrated security.

Unfortunately, it simply does not work.  Things break all the time with Fortify on Demand, and you have little ability to debug the problems.  You are forced to open a Fortify Support help ticket.  Fortify Support is slow.  When things fail, their knee-jerk reaction is that you are doing something wrong and they tell you to try something different.  They make little effort to debug problems.  If you  are an expert on Fortify (knowing all sorts of things about fpr files and what to look for when things break), you can pin Fortify Support down to prove that the problem is in their environment.  But rather than fixing it, they will encourage you to not use their plugin and do something else instead. So, the short summary is that if you want automation, Fortify on Demand is not for you.  Their sales people won't say that, but when you pin them down, that's what they push you to accept.

Now to be clear, one thing you need to understand is that unless you are an expert, you may think that the VSTS plugin is working fine, and your developers write awesome code so that's why Fortify is not finding much.  Don't be deceived.  Look at the fpr file.  You can find out what is scanned, and you will often find that a number of things didn't work.  In my latest case, I am finding that none of the controller files scanned, which is the most important part of scanning an application.  I am mind boggled that Fortify Support thinks it is not their responsibility to fix the problem in their environment.

Pros:

- You do not need to maintain environments
- Less false positives and less nonsense in the scan results

Cons:

- Does not work well for automation
- Inability to debug problems without Fortify Support
- Fortify Support is slow
- When the problems are complex and in the Fortify environment, Fortify Support will do anything and everything possible to try to avoid solving the problem.  It gets really frustrating when they ask you to spend a lot of effort doing something else that is clearly irrelevant had they did some basic inspection into the problem.  (Step #1 in debugging should be looking at the payload and fpr file -- but they really try hard not to do that)
- Even though less nonsense in the scan results, still nonsense slips through.
- Fortify scanning is slow
- Fortify requires being able to build (for most languages) to perform its best scanning, and this will bite you in a number of ways
- Fortify is not so developer friendly

Comment: Do we have any integration document for integrating Fortify On premise with Jenkins and Github.

Answer (score 0):

"On-premise" means you're running the Fortify tools yourself, installed on hardware you manage (AWS instances, developer workstations, etc).

"On-demand" means you're using Fortify as a service (the vendor refers to it as "Security-as-a-Service"). The marketing material indicates that you send off your source code to be analyzed by their team (using Fortify), and you'll be sent back a report of the results.